# Adding NZ to an expression in Access

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I feel like what I am trying to achieve is simple. So I must be missing something rather basic.

**My current expression:**

```
Total Aged: Sum(CCur([Aged Debt Amount]))
```

This used to work fine. However, I now have some of my data with empty cells (NULL)

This is causing the expression to break. My thought was to add in an NZ but doesn't work. Am I putting the NZ in the right part of the expression?

**Methods tried:**

```
Total Aged: NZ(Sum(CCur([Aged Debt Amount])),0)

Total Aged: Sum(NZ(CCur([Aged Debt Amount]),0))

Total Aged: Sum(CCur(NZ([Aged Debt Amount],0)))
```

**New method I have tried that didn't work:**

```
sum(isnull([Aged Debt Amount],0))
```

**Error Received:**

> Invalid use of Null

Comment: `Sum(CCur(NZ([Aged Debt Amount],0)))` should work as far as I know. Did you get _Invalid use of null_ when using that? What's the field type of `[Aged Debt Amount]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't need CCur if the field is of data type Currency. Thus:

```
Total Aged: Sum(Nz([Aged Debt Amount],0))
```